# Downloads folder keeps crashing

Tags: windows-10

I have Windows 10 PRO. ( I got a 32GB, Intel i9 )

I was trying to download a PDF doc from my Google drive. ( The PDF doc was a few papers that I scanned myself. It was not some random doc from the internet) The file name was VoltageB.pdf

It had 8 pages. I just needed pages 3-5 and page 7.

I located the file in Google drive and then clicked on it.
Google opened the file and there was a 'print' icon on the top right.

I chose 'Save as PDF' from the pull down menu.
Under the pull down for 'Pages' I chose 'Custom' and in the box right below, I entered  3-5,7 because I wanted to save only pages 3-5 and page 7. ( This is how I split my PDFs instead of using some random PDF splitting website).
Then I hit save.

Nothing happened for about 60 seconds. Wondering what was happening to the file and why it was taking so long, I went back to the Downloads folder and saw the new file there.

Then within 2 seconds:

1. The Downloads folder crashed ( It was behaving as if I closed the Downloads file window ).
2. The screen went super bright for 1 second and went back to normal brightness.

The file name is extremely long:
`APm4d93,d,lf94,e[phsn w3-054rmf93mti8sjmf93t4tm4j.pdf`

Later, I opened CMD as an Admin.

1. In CMD, I navigated to `C:\Users\bobk\Downloads`. I could see the file in the directory.
2. I tried to delete it by typing the following in CMD:
   `del APm4d93,d,lf94,e[phsn w3-054rmf93mti8sjmf93t4tm4j.pdf`
3. After hitting the enter key, CMD gave me a message that said, `The system cannot find the path specified`

I tried doing a bunch of things using advice from Google, but none worked.

How do I stop the Downloads window from shutting down every time I open it?

Is there a way to create a new Downloads folder, even if it means that I have to delete the old `Downloads` folder and lose all the files in the old folder.

Answer (score 1):

### Things to Try

1. Quoting the Filename
2. Short Filename
3. Disabling String Parsing
4. Running CHKDSK
5. Using a Live CD (USB)

##### 1. Quoting the Filename

```
del "APm4d93,d,lf94,e[phsn w3-054rmf93mti8sjmf93t4tm4j.pdf"
```

##### 2. Short File Name

If Windows short file names ([8.3 filenames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#short-vs-long-names)) are enabled.
Get the short filename by typing `dir /x` then:

```
example filename `APM4D9~1.pdf`

del  APM4D9~1.pdf
```

##### 3. Disabling String Parsing

Prefixing `\\?\` to a path string tells the Windows APIs to disable all string parsing and to send the string that follows it straight to the file system. It turns off the automatic expansion of the path string.   <sup>[ Source: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) ]</sup>

First, find the *real* path to your Downloads folder. Then using that path:

```
# example path: "C:\Users\Fawaz Al Lawz\Downloads"

del "\\?\C:\Users\Fawaz Al Lawz\Downloads\APm4d93,d,lf94,e[phsn w3-054rmf93mti8sjmf93t4tm4j.pdf"
```

##### 4. Running CHKDSK

Windows [CHKDSK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk) can check the file system for logical and physical errors.

If used without parameters, [CHKDSK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk) displays only the status of the volume and does not fix any errors. If used with the `/f`, `/r`, `/x`, or `/b` parameters, it fixes errors on the volume

**NOTE:** It is always recommended to have a backup of your system before attempting any repairs.

`/f` switch will fix errors on the disk.

```
CHKDSK C: /f
```

##### 5. Using a Live CD (USB)

I'm partial to [SystemRescue](https://www.system-rescue.org/) which is a Linux-based tool for Linux and **Windows** computers.  It provides an easy way to make changes to your system without using the existing OS. It includes a lot of utilities and filesystem tools.

[SystemRescue](https://www.system-rescue.org/) requires no installation and can be booted from a CD or USB stick.  The kernel supports ext4, xfs, btrfs, vfat, and **ntfs**, as well as network filesystems such as Samba and NFS.

###### SystemRescue Media Creation

**•**   [USB on Windows](https://www.system-rescue.org/Installing-SystemRescue-on-a-USB-memory-stick/)
    **•**   [CD/DVD on Windows](https://www.system-rescue.org/manual/Downloading_and_burning/)

###### File Removal Instructions

1. **Create** Live CD or USB ([SystemRescue](https://www.system-rescue.org/) or some other)
2. **Boot** PC using Live CD or USB
   <sup>Can be to a GUI or Terminal depending on tool and your  preference</sup>
3. **Navigate** to Downloads folder using *real* path
   <sup>*real* explained in "**3. Disabling String Parsing**" section</sup>
4. **Delete** the offending file
5. **Shut down** PC, remove media, boot normally.

<sup>***** If using [SystemRescue](https://www.system-rescue.org/) , when booting to the Graphical User Interface (GUI) you will find an application called [Thunar](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/working-with-files-and-folders) which is a similar concept to **Windows Explorer**.  Here is a file operation [cheat sheet for Thunar](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/working-with-files-and-folders)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You may use `dir /x` to display the short file names in the
`8.3` format.

Your file's short name will look similar to `APm4d9~1.pdf`,
and you may then use this short name to delete it with the `del`
command.